# Writing Oracle Remote Table into csv file causing Rstudio to crash

Tags: r, rstudio, oracle-sqldeveloper, remote-server, dbplyr

I am using the function collect() from dbplyr to write a remote table (created with an SQL query and an Oracle Database server) into an csv file. However, Rstudio keeps crashing everytime I try to do this.
FYI, this table has about 17k rows and 5 columns. Is that too much to handle ?
Is there a workaround this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd first attempt to run the script in R itself (not using Rstudio) and see if it is still crashing. At least it points to whether the issue is rstudio related or not.

Comment: @Phil it still crashes...

Comment: It's a little odd because 17k * 5 is not large enough to run into memory issues. What if you try just a tiny parcel of that? Is there something peculiar about the data?

Comment: @Phil I tried extracting a sample with : `write.csv(t2 %>%filter(ID_DEAL == id)%>%slice_min(CREATION_DATE_FIRST, n=10)%>%collect(),'./DEALS.csv')`. Same thing happens. I'm starting to think it's because of the filter ? I am filtering the oracle tbl by comparing the variable ID_DEAL to a vector of characters, stored locally.

Comment: Try just with `filter(t2, ID_DEAL == id)` (I assume `id` is another object you assigned beforehand containing one value) and see if that runs ok, then add `slice_min()` etc until it crashes.

Comment: If `id` is vector of length greater than 1, use `filter(t2, ID_DEAL %in% id)` instead.

Comment: @Phil  `filter(t2, ID_DEAL %in% id)` makes it crash.

Comment: It's difficult to help further without some reproducible example. If possible, pasting the output of `dput(head(t2, 50))` and `dput(id)` as part of your question would help determine the cause.

Comment: The error could also be located in the SQL translation. You can use `tmp = t2 %>%filter(ID_DEAL == id)%>%slice_min(CREATION_DATE_FIRST, n=10)` and `show_query(tmp)` to review the SQL translation. Including this in the question would also help.

Comment: Some more ideas. 

 - Try `compute()` (if you have permissions to do this). This would confirm whether the query can be executed (though it seems weird that "Rstudio keeps crashing" … more expected would be the query not working).
 - Try variations on `select()` to see if there's specific columns that are problematic.
 -  Try variations on `collect(n = 10)` to see if there's specific rows that are problematic.